# VPN software to easily manage connections

Tags: linux, remote-access, vpn

I'm looking for a service that can manage multiple VPN connections. I'm a developer and my goal is to connect to a specific VPN whenever I need to code and debug on a specific target.

Looking on the Internet I found a lot of "VPN" services but they are for surfing privately... instead I want to create VPNs with my own machines running in remote places.

**Question 1**: what are the correct English search terms to find this kind of VPN services avoiding the ones related to surfing privately?

**Question 2**: I'm able (with some effort) to create a VPN between to machines using OpenVPN but it's not very straighforward... and because I'm going to manage dozen of machines it would be a nightmare. Is there a software that make this task easier? Like Zoho Assist for remote desktop where you can easily connect to your machines without dealing with IP/NAT and so on.

Comment: You might look at SSH tunneling.  The NSA actually has a VPN they publically contribute to, let me see if i can find it.

Comment: Can you clarify if the machines you want to manage are on the same subnet?

Comment: @Gordon, the goal is to see those machines under the same subnet through the VPN connection, even if their local address (obtained via DHCP) is different.

Answer (score 2):

The NSA has released a VPN called goSecure.  I have not tried it.  Unfortunately the VPN craze has made it very difficult to locate information on creating your own.   You might also look into a hardware solution.  Higher end and prosumer routers like the ubiquiti edgerouter series sometimes have built in vpn portals.

Question 1: try "IP tunneling", "SSH tunneling", maybe "IP bridging". EDIT: Adding "Site to site VPN" to my suggestions.

Question 2: unless you're using something that tunnels out to a web interface like teamviewer, you're going to have to deal with IP.  If all of the machines are on the same network you shouldn't have to do NAT, just careful subnetting and route definition.

Comment: Each machine runs in a different place across the world, each one using a different network settings and IP address (usually the local router assign them in DHCP). But when I *see* them (one per time, I'm not interested to connect to multiple of them) I would like they keep my local subnet in order to reach them easily.

Comment: I was envisioning the other direction (you're remote, they're centralized).  So the VPNs my multiple employers have used (I'm an end user, not admin) create a virtual NIC and give that a corporate-subneted ip.  They then route the corporate traffic through that, the software encrypts it and sends it over the Physical NIC to the VPN concatenator at work.  The only NAT would need to happen from the central router to the Concatenator.